# c++ class member call error C3861

Tags: c++

I'm at a bit of a loss. I know I'm missing something, however I'm not seeing it.  I'm getting error C3861 in reference to the class member functions not being identified. I was looking through other answers to similar problems and most of them had to do with prototyping issues and order of calls.  So, I'm wondering where I'm screwing up at.  I know I should see it, but I'm operating on a significant lack of sleep this weekend.

```
main.cpp:
#include "Date.h"

int main()
{
int day = 1;
int month = 1;
int year = 2000;
int addedDays;

displayDate(day, month, year);
cout << "Enter how many days you would like to add:  ";
cin >> addedDays;
cout << endl;
setDate(day, month, year);
addDays(day, month, year, addedDays);
displayDate(day, month, year);

return 0;}
//====================================
Date.cpp
#include "Date.h"

Date::Date(){}
Date::Date(int day, int month, int year) 
{
this->day = day;
this->month = month;
this->year = year;
}

Date::~Date() {}

void Date::setDate(int day, int month, int year)
{
this->day = day;
this->month = month;
this->year = year;
}

void Date::addDays(int day, int month, int year, int addedDays)
{
day = day + addedDays;
while (day > 30)        //Test if day function needs to be cycled.
{
    month++;
    day = day - 30;
    if(month>12)        //Test if month function needs to be cycled.
    {
        year++;
        month = month - 12;
    }
}
}

void Date::displayDate(int day, int month, int year)
{
cout << "The current date is:  " << day << ", " << month << ", " << year << endl;
}
//======================================
Date.h:
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
private:
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;

public:
    Date();
    Date(int day, int month, int year);
    ~Date();
    void setDate(int day, int month, int year);
    void addDays(int day, int month, int year, int addedDays);
    void displayDate(int day, int month, int year);
};
```

Comment: When you call `displayDate(day, month, year);` in your main, did you mean to call `Date.displayDate(day, month, year);` ?

Comment: You can't just call member functions of your Date class, you need a Date object.

Comment: Add sensible indents to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
private:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

public:
    Date();
    Date(int day, int month, int year);
    ~Date();

    void setDate(int day, int month, int year);
    // don't need day, month, year since they are accessible in the class
    void addDays(int addedDays); 
    void displayDate();
};
```

The implementation file

```
#include "Date.h"

// if no day, month, year specified when object is created, set each of them to 1
Date::Date() : day(1), month(1), year(1) 
{}
Date::Date(int day, int month, int year) 
{
    this->day = day;
    this->month = month;
    this->year = year;
}

Date::~Date() 
{}

void Date::setDate(int day, int month, int year)
{
    this->day = day;
    this->month = month;
    this->year = year;
}

void Date::addDays(int addedDays)
{
    this->day = this->day + addedDays;  // or could do day += addedDays
    if(this->day > 30)            //Test if day function needs to be cycled.
    {
        this->month++;
        this->day = 1;
        if(this->month>12)        //Test if month function needs to be cycled.
        {
            this->year++;
            this->month = 1;
        }
    }
}

void Date::displayDate()
{
    cout << "The current date is:  " << this->day << ", " << this->month << ", "<<      this->year << endl;
}
```

The main cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"

int main()
{
    int day = 1;
    int month = 1;
    int year = 2000;
    int addedDays = 0;

    // declare a date object
    Date date(day, month, year); 

    // call the displayDate function using the date object
    date.displayDate(); 

    std::cout << "Enter how many days you would like to add:  ";
    std::cin >> addedDays;
    std::cout << endl;

    // add the days by calling the addDays function through the date object
    date.addDays(addedDays);
    date.displayDate();

    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if there are any mistakes

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The big reason for the while loop in the month checker was to cover instances where more than 30 days were added.  So instead of resetting it to zero I'd cycle through a month and update the appropriate year.  But I really appreciate the additional help on the rest of it.  Thanks a ton man.

Answer (score 1):

You have a class, however you do not create a Date object to use the functions on. You must use a date object to be able to use the functions.

In your main function:

```
int main()
{
    int day = 1;
    int month = 1;
    int year = 2000;
    int addedDays;
    Date today(day, month, year);
    today.displayDate(day, month, year);
    cout << "Enter how many days you would like to add:  ";
    cin >> addedDays;
    cout << endl;
    today.addDays(day, month, year, addedDays);
    today.displayDate(day, month, year);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that your `addDays()` function does not work correctly. You can possibly implement the approach [found here](https://alcor.concordia.ca//~gpkatch/gdate-algorithm.html) by converting date to days, adding, and then converting back.